# Data frame: How to compare current row to some other rows without looping?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following `df` and use-case, I'd like to find and set something in all rows for which exist another row satisfying a condition e.g.

```
df <- data.frame(X=c('a','b','c'), Y=c('a','c','d'))
> df
    X   Y
1   a   a
2   b   c
3   c   d
```

I'd like to find those rows whos Y value is the same as X value in **another row**. In the example above would be row #2 is true because `Y = c` and row #3 has `X = c`. Note that row #1 does not satisfy the condition.

Something like:

```
df$Flag <- find(df, Y == X_in_another_row(df))
```

Comment: Are entries unique within each column?

Comment: For clarification: if we have another row `df[4,] = e  a` then would row 1 be an included or excluded solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1**

For each `Y`, we check if any value in `X` (other than in the same row) matches.

```
sapply(1:NROW(df), function(i) df$Y[i] %in% df$X[-i])
#[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

If indices are necessary, wrap the whole thing in `which`

```
which(sapply(1:NROW(df), function(i) df$Y[i] %in% df$X[-i]))
#[1] 2
```

**2** (not tested well)

```
df <- data.frame(X=c('a','b','c'), Y=c('a','c','d'), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
temp = outer(df$X, df$Y, "==")  #Check equality among values of X and Y
diag(temp) = FALSE              #Set diagonal values as FALSE (for same row)
colSums(temp) > 0
#[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Comment: without looping...?

Answer (score 1):

```
which(match(df$Y,df$X)!=1:nrow(df))
```

Comment: wow! interesting solution ... some explanation for self containment?

Comment: @Damiano This works fine for any table in which all values in X are distinct, I guess.

Comment: @Frank ahh, makes sense... I was experimenting on an X with duplicated values... :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work.

```
df <- data.frame(X= c(1,2,3,4,5,3,2,1), Y = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8))
which(with(df,  (X %in% Y) & (X != Y)))
```

Works on the original data.frame, if we set stringsasfactors=FALSE

```
df <- data.frame(X=c('a','b','c'), Y=c('a','c','d'), stringsAsFactors = F)    
which(with(df,  (X %in% Y) & (X != Y)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Quite convoluted but I'll put it here anyway. This should work even if there are repeated values in X.
For example with the following dataframe `df2`:

```
df2 = data.frame(X=c('a','b','c','a','d'), Y=c('a','c','d','e','b'))
  X Y
1 a a
2 b c
3 c d
4 a e
5 d b


## Specifying the same factor levels allows us to get a square matrix 
df2$X = factor(df2$X,levels=union(df2$X,df2$Y))
df2$Y = factor(df2$Y,levels=union(df2$X,df2$Y))
m = as.matrix(table(df2))
valY = rowSums(m)*colSums(m)-diag(m)
which(df2$Y %in% names(valY)[as.logical(valY)])
[1] 1 2 3 5
```

Answer (score 1):

Essentially you want to know whether `Y` is in `X` but you want the condition to be `FALSE` when `X == Y`:

```
df$Z <- with(df, (Y != X) & (Y %in% X))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Assume you want to use position 4, value 'c', to find all the rows that Y is 'c'
df <- data.frame(X = c('a', 'b', 'd', 'c'),
                 Y = c('a', 'c', 'c', 'd'))


row <- 4 # assume the desire row is position 4

val <- as.character( df[(row),'X'] ) # get the character and turn it into character type

df[df$Y == val,]
# Result
#   X Y
# 2 b c
# 3 d c
```